# How to use expand modifiers with Vim map/filter?

Tags: vim, vi

I'm trying to get the list of absolute paths to my buffers, but cannot work out how to add the `:p` to `expand` as in `expand("v:val:p")` into map.

```
let l:buffers = filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)')
let l:buffiles = map(copy(l:buffers), 'expand(bufname(v:val).":p")')
```

The above does not work and append `:p` to end of each filename loaded as buffer. .e.g.

```
  ['.vim/vimrc:p']
```

What's the right way to pass an expand modifier inside map or filter expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way is `:h getbufinfo()`.

```
let l:files = map(getbufinfo({'buflisted': 1}), 'v:val.name')
```

Concerning arbitrary file name expansion, it is what `:h fnamemodify()` is used for.

```
echo fnamemodify('filename.ext', ':p')
```

On the other hand, `:h expand()` performs an expansion of `:h cmdline-special`.

Comment: I disagree on `getbufinfo()` being the right way. Simpler? Faster? Definitively! Right way? It depends. It doesn't work on older versions of vim we may still have to use (RH6 quite likely, and may be RH7, I'm less sure). The _right way_ depends on the objectives and the constrains we have.

Comment: @LucHermitte Well, sometimes it takes a lot to choose words wisely. And so I'm used to simply copying them from a question. Mea culpa. But just in case, I also mentioned `fnamemodify()`, because it definitely might be of use too.

Comment: I know too well the time it takes to write answers... Anyway, you had already earned my +1 here for `fnamemodify()` ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'm on Vim 8 so that ``getbufinfo`` made things simpler to me.